# Getting RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException while writing into parcel

Tags: java, android

I try to send Parcelable data through intents but I'm getting:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = java.util.HashMap)

The parcelable class has been generated with the android parcelable generator plugin.
I believe the hashmap cannot be parcelable this way, so what would be the solution?

Here is my code:

```
public class Menu extends Product implements Parcelable {
    private HashMap<Option,ArrayList<Article>> options = new HashMap<>();

    private int calories = 0;

    public Menu(String name, double price, String description, String pictureSrc){
        super(name,price,description,pictureSrc);
        for(Option option:Option.values()){
            ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
            articles.add(new Article(""));
            articles.add(new Article("Choisir un article ..."));
            options.put(option,articles);
        }
    }

    public HashMap<Option,ArrayList<Article>> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(HashMap<Option,ArrayList<Article>> options) {
        this.options = options;

        this.calories = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for(Option option:options.keySet()){
            for(Article article:options.get(i)){
                calories += article.getCalories();
            }
        }
    }

    public void addOption(Option option, Article article){
        article.addIncludedInMenu(this);
        if(options.containsKey(option))
            options.get(option).add(article);
        else{
            ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
            articles.add(article);
            options.put(option,articles);
        }

        calories += article.getCalories();
    }

    public void removeOption(Option option, Article article){
        article.removeIncludedInMenu(this);
        this.options.get(option).remove(article);
        calories -= article.getCalories();
    }


    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj==this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeSerializable(this.options);
        dest.writeInt(this.calories);
    }

    protected Menu(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        this.options = (HashMap<Option, ArrayList<Article>>) in.readSerializable();
        this.calories = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Menu> CREATOR = new Creator<Menu>() {
        @Override
        public Menu createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Menu(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Menu[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Menu[size];
        }
    };
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList already implements serializable.
So, another idea to approach your problem would be:
Pass the ArrayLists using the option as the extra name, and where do you need, you can just iterate again.

Something like this:

```
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
for(Option option:Option.values()){
    ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    articles.add(new Article(""));
    articles.add(new Article("Choisir un article ..."));
    bundle.putSerializable(String.valueOf(option), articles);
}
```

Then, in the part receiving the intent you can just

```
for(Option option:Option.values()){
   if (getIntent().hasExtra(String.valueOf(option))){
      ArrayList<Article> articles = getSerializableExtra(option);
      // add to your hashmap
   }
}
```